# Does Trac provide URLs that are callable for GitLab Web Hooks?

Tags: gitlab, webhooks, trac

Is it possible to notify a Trac installation about new revisions by calling a URL?

I have that GitLab server that allows me to trigger WebHooks when new revisions were pushed. Is there an interface on my Trac server that I could call in order to notify about the new revisions?

Comment: You could try using the [trac-github plugin](https://github.com/trac-hacks/trac-github). It might need some modifications to work with GitLab web hooks, but should be close to what you are looking for. Feel free to open a ticket for trac-github if you create a patch to make it work with GitLab, or have some specific questions. I also spotted [gitlab-trac-integration](https://github.com/georgethomasuk/gitlab-trac-integration) when searching GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a workaround for this.

1. set up the git mirror in the trac repository, per instruction in [trac-github plugin](https://github.com/trac-hacks/trac-github)
2. Instead of setting up a webhook in gitlab, you could set up a crontab job in the trac server such that, for every 10 minutes (or whatever frequency you find comportable), update the mirror repository in trac server, and **trigger the corresponding `post-receive` hooks**. This [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567518/local-git-hook-for-git-remote-update) contains a fully functional script.

This is not ideal, but actually works for any git mirrors in Trac, even if you don't have the web hook access.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with RjOllos that the [trac-github plugin](https://github.com/trac-hacks/trac-github) is the best way to accomplish the integration that you want. One of the [main features](https://github.com/trac-hacks/trac-github#features) of the plugin is that it supports "direct changeset [TracLinks](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracLinks) to GitHub's repository browser."  Per the Trac site, TracLinks are a fundamental feature of Trac, because they allow easy hyperlinking between the various entities in the system — such as changesets and commit messages. This sounds like the feature you are looking for to provide links from Trac to revisions in Git.

In version [2.3](https://github.com/trac-hacks/trac-github#23) of the plugin, it states that they have added "Support webhook signature verification for post commit hooks."

They also provide some nice [setup steps](https://github.com/trac-hacks/trac-github#setup) which can sometime be lacking with other Trac plugins.